# Retrieving keys from a json array file(dynamically) and use it for d3js functions

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to retrieve keys from external json array dynamically and use them in d3js functions which generates bar charts. Here is the json code.

```
[
 {   
    "Interns": 5,
    "Projects": 10,
    "Time":"Jan"
},

{
    "Interns": 16,
    "Projects": 20,
    "Time":"Feb"
}
]
```

I want to retrieve all the keys and use them in d3 functions which uses data to draw bars in bar chart.Below, an example I wrote `d.Time` but what if I don't know what keys i have been given??

```
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Time; }));
```

here is what i tried, this functions stores the keys in an array `mykeys`. The `data` in `getKeys(data)` refers to parameter from `d3.json()` function

```
var getKeys = function(arr) {
   var key, keys=[];
   for(var i=0; i< (arr.length - (arr.length - 1)); i++) {
       for(key in arr[i]) {
           keys.push(key);
       }
   }
   return keys;
}
var myKeys = getKeys(data); // Gives ["Interns","Projects","Time"]
```

Now if i use `console.log` mykeys[2] it displays `Time` but when i use `d.mykeys[2]` in the above domain function, it doesn't seem to work ??
why so ??? Please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your are trying to access a property of `d` by it's name as a string. `mykeys[2]` holds that string ("Time"), so it should be `d[mykeys[2]]` which is equal to `d["Time"]` which in turn is equal to d.Time ...